# Camera and motherboard with Camera Serial Interface

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, video-camera, video-capture

So I came across this great [article](https://hackaday.com/2019/08/10/660-fps-raspberry-pi-video-captures-the-moment-in-extreme-slo-mo/) about getting 660 frames per second from a Raspberry PI and its default camera, and was wondering is there any way to crank the setup up with possibly higher frame rate camera and faster processing hardware?

As far as I understand there should be a [MIPI](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/communications/article/21799475/understanding-mipi-alliance-interface-specifications) [Camera Serial Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Serial_Interface) ([more](http://www.camera-module.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-mipi-csi-2-vs-csi-3.html)) (and [more](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20190926005230/en/New-Version-Widely-Camera-Imaging-Interface%E2%80%94MIPI-CSI-2%E2%80%94Designed)) on both camera and recording device, and the rest is just a software issue. I did some search and found something like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/IMX307-MIPI-CSI-2-2MP-Star-Light-ISP-Camera-for-Raspberry-Pi-and-Jetson-Nano/293496855693?hash=item4455c69c8d:m:mKxwJQTODRxnqP7tTL_u-7A).

So asking for any research advice, maybe there are some specific keywords I can search for, or maybe some brand.

Comment: _is there any way to crank the setup up, perhaps with a higher frame rate camera, and faster processing hardware?_ Yes.  -  Wish I could dig into this for you. EG&G https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapatronic_camera used optoelectronic shutters for this purpose. Knowing your budget would be _very_ helpful, otherwise this turns into a 'how high is up?' question.

Comment: I know high speed cameras are extremely expensive, but seeing this guy's setup, can I say couple hundred bucks for 1000fps at some ok-ish quality? can't really think of any high-end cameras with CSI port.. or maybe there are other possible ways to connect it?

Comment: well let's say 480p, in general I'm just looking for some research advices on what kind of hardware works for it

Comment: let the "couple hundred" be $200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post explains how the poster created a [four-lane board he's selling](https://www.circuitvalley.com/2020/02/diy-imx219-4-lane-mipi-breakout-board-raspberry-pi-camera-fpga-4-lane-mipi-csi.html) to double throughput, and also provided a lot of [technical background](https://www.circuitvalley.com/2020/02/imx219-camera-mipi-csi-receiver-fpga-lattice-raspberry-pi-camera.html).

This [seller of Pi cameras](http://www.camera-module.com/product/raspberrypicameramod/) may also have useful gear.